# Crypto++ and ECC + ChaCha20

Tags: c++, crypto++

I am not very familiar with the library yet.
What I need is what ECIES does but *without* appending MAC to the message.
I want to choose a curve on which I would perform ECDH.  I need to derive a symmetric key and encrypt data with ChaCha.

I've looked into the Encrypt function in pubkey.h which seems to achieve eveything I want:

```
void Encrypt(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, const byte *plaintext, size_t plaintextLength, byte *ciphertext, const NameValuePairs &parameters = g_nullNameValuePairs) const
{
    const DL_KeyAgreementAlgorithm<T> &agreeAlg = this->GetKeyAgreementAlgorithm();
    const DL_KeyDerivationAlgorithm<T> &derivAlg = this->GetKeyDerivationAlgorithm();
    const DL_SymmetricEncryptionAlgorithm &encAlg = this->GetSymmetricEncryptionAlgorithm();
    const DL_GroupParameters<T> &params = this->GetAbstractGroupParameters();
    const DL_PublicKey<T> &key = this->GetKeyInterface();

    Integer x(rng, Integer::One(), params.GetMaxExponent());
    Element q = params.ExponentiateBase(x);
    params.EncodeElement(true, q, ciphertext);
    unsigned int elementSize = params.GetEncodedElementSize(true);
    ciphertext += elementSize;

    Element z = agreeAlg.AgreeWithEphemeralPrivateKey(params, key.GetPublicPrecomputation(), x);

    SecByteBlock derivedKey(encAlg.GetSymmetricKeyLength(plaintextLength));
    derivAlg.Derive(params, derivedKey, derivedKey.size(), z, q, parameters);

    encAlg.SymmetricEncrypt(rng, derivedKey, plaintext, plaintextLength, ciphertext, parameters);
}
```

, *but* would you advise on how to approach the subject in the most elegant way? I see ECIES is ready to use out-of-the-box. How to approach implementation of such a custom scheme, any example? What I need is a small elegant approach.

In the above *Encrypt* function I do not see where MAC is appended, yet, this function is used directly for benchmarking ECIES (in BenchMarkEncryption in bench2.cpp) did I miss something?

Comment: Why would you trust the user to provide a secure random number generator in the function call? That can lead to both complication and a poor choice of a CSPRNG.

Comment: that is an internal function used by Crypto++. It is public however it is not advised by any Crypto++ documentation. Crypto++ hides such features for a typical user. Yet, it allows for much more flexibility than Libsodium for example where user is considered irresponsible. But, as we are at RNGs the official security report of other libraries often highlited allowing users to provide RNGs as irresponsible. oh well. Comment not related to question by the way. And once again it is used internally by Crypto++, yet public.

Comment: I agree, that RNG as a parameter to encrypt function is not the best design decision - that's for sure. Still, the library allows for much more flexibility than other libraries that I'm familiar with, which is why it received my attention. If one is to design  scheme of one's own it seems like a much more welcoming place than NaS or sodium, Bouncy Castle maybe would do but I'm working with C++

Comment: @zaph - The Crypto++ library provides a number of RNGs. An `AutoSeededRandomPool` is recommended, which is an AES/OFB generator seeded from the OS non-blocking pool (`/dev/urandom` or `CryptGenRandom`). Other generators are available, like VIA Padlock RNG, `RDRAND`, `RDSEED`, NIST DRBG. If needed during debugging, users can wire-up a deterministic generator for reproducible results. It is probably worth remembering history and RSA Data Security Inc use of hard-coded Dual-EC RNG. Also see [RandomNumberGenerator](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: @Rafal - What is your question or problem? Forgive my ignorance, but its not clear to me. You seem to want to encrypt with ChaCha20, then you make a leap to ECIES. ECIES is an integrated system. ECIES output is the `{K,C,T}` tuple, where K is the encrypted common secret, C is the ciphertext, and T is the authentication tag. You cannot disgorge the authentication tag. Also see [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: @jww - please forgive my poor explanation of the problem. I want to 1) generate ephemeral key pair on an EC of my choosing 2) be able to perform ECDH with a given public key 3) be able to to run a key derivation function - HKDF 4) be able to use chacha20 with the derived key. Like I said, what I need is very similar to what ECIES does in terms of performed steps. The problem is  - which blocks from the library, should I use,  to accomplish these steps. Which data structures, objects etc. In terms of ECC, the documentation only shows how to use the 'bigger' blocks such as ECIES.

Comment: the more I read, the more I find. CryptoPP wiki shows how to do ECDH, anyway a little advise from someone familiar with the library would be welcome.

Comment: I've already found everything I need thanks to the Crypto++ wiki; so unless someone gives an answer within 2 days, I'll answer my question.